# How to use a charactercomparator to compare whether the characters in a string is the same or not?

Tags: java, string, boolean, iteration, comparator

I have a method `public boolean same` which takes in a string `w` and I'm trying to use a character comparator `d` to check whether each character in the string is the same with each character in the reversed version of the string or not (a palindrome basically).

So what I've done is I've taken my string `w` and created another string `S` that returns the reversed version of the given string. After that, I have created a for loop and used my character comparator to compare each character in the two strings that I have, and the method would return True if all characters are the same and false otherwise.

Here is my code so far:

```
public boolean same(String w, CharacterComparator<Character> d) {
    String S = "";
    for (int i = w.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        S = S + w.charAt(i);
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < w.length()-1; x++){
    if (d.equalChars(w.charAt(x), S.charAt(x))) {
        return true;}
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, there seems to be a problem in my implementation of this as it's causing an error. Can anyone please explain what am I doing wrong and correct me?

Comment: There are two bugs in this. 

1. `x <w.length() -1`. Here you're not comparing the last character so correct condition would be `x < w.length()`.

2. The function should return true when all the characters match. The current implementation will return true even if there is only 1 match. So you can toggle both, the conditions and return statements. It should be : if at least 1 character is different return false and at last return `true` if there is no mismatch.

Comment: @SanketMakani what do I have to edit in my for loop to make sure it returns True if ALL of it are the same?

Comment: Current implementation : "If there is atleast 1 match, return `true`. At last, return `false`."


What do you need? : "If there is atleast 1 mismatch, return `false`. At last, return `true`."

So you need to toggle `if` conditions and also the return statements.

Comment: @SanketMakani so can I do (!d.equalChars(w.charAt(x), S.charAt(x))) instead, since ! means not equal right? please correct my syntax if Im wrong

Comment: Yup, Do that and also switch the return statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has 2 problems

1. is about reversing the string
2. is about the return condition is not true, it return true even if there is only one characters match.

Try this code:

```
public boolean same(String w, CharacterComparator<Character> d) {
    String S = new StringBuilder(w).reverse().toString();

    for (int x = 0; x < w.length()-1; x++) {
        if (!d.equalChars(w.charAt(x), S.charAt(x))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This does not use the `CharacterComparator<Character> d`. It ("reverses" and) compares many more characters than necessary.